# What's the difference between hashtx and rawtx in ZeroMQ of bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, zeromq

I'm trying to use [ZeroMQ integration feature](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.13.1/doc/zmq.md) from bitcoind.

According to docs it supports four topic:

- hashtx
- hashblock
- rawblock
- rawtx

Sadly, they are not very well documented.

So, what is the difference between raw/hash topics?

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I found out that RAW topics actually include entire body of transaction/block descriptor.

See, [Raw Transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions).

Actually, you could explore the transaction descriptor content in JSON format by first converting binary data to HEX-string and then by [pasting it to the **blockchain.info** tool](https://blockchain.info/decode-tx) or by using RPC call of bitcoind: **decoderawtransaction**.